# Create custom blade directive in laravel similar to section or yield

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I want to create a blade directive for bootstrap model something like below

```
@model('modelid')
   <div>Model body content</div>
@endmodel
```

Which should generate a complete bootstrap model in html,
How to create a custom blade directive to capture the html content and process it?

Comment: Finally found the answer from here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34750226/laravel-blade-custom-method-for-html-block

Comment: That may have solved your problem, but it doesn't answer the question, which is being able to access the content within two custom directives.

Answer (score 1):

Im assuming you mean bootstrap 'modal' (correct me if I'm wrong)... you could try adding this to your AppServiceProvider boot() method

```
 Blade::directive('modal', function ($modalid) {
       $html = '<some html utilising $modalid>'; 
       return $html;
    });
```

Comment: Yes, the bootstrap model,  but my question is, how to capture the html between  `@model` and `@endmodel` into the directive function and add model header and footer and return it to the view?

Comment: Yeah it gets difficult because you can't pass multiple parameters to the directive definition - i found : https://github.com/arrilot/laravel-widgets/blob/master/src/ServiceProvider.php - arrilot shows a good way of working around this by wrapping the `Blade::directive` and injecting more data in the 'use' part of the closure which means you could maybe generate all of the html in the directive. I think the link you found is pretty good too

Comment: I just got what you were saying about capturing the html between the tags - sry

Comment: Looking at the source for blade in compilers/BladeCompiler.php and view/Factory.php - blade starts a section with `ob_start();` and stops it with `ob_get_clean();`   anything you came up with would have to be at the same level - you'd probably have to extend blade.

Comment: Did this work - i know its a while ago but would be good to get the rep for the answer