# How can I capture the content wrapped in a pair of custom Blade directives?

Tags: php, laravel, directive, laravel-blade

I am trying to write a custom Blade directive which can modify the content and return it, something like this:

```
<div class="some-text">
    @uppercase
    This is a line of text.
    @enduppercase
</div>
```

which would render in the HTML as following:

```
<div class="some-text">
    THIS IS A LINE OF TEXT.     
</div>
```

What I do NOT wish to know is how to do the following:

```
@uppercase('This is a line of text')
```

How can I capture all the content within the start and end directives, process and then return them to the view?

Note: There is a similar sounding question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35803701/create-custom-blade-directive-in-laravel-similar-to-section-or-yield), with a comment linking to another question that purportedly has the answer, but it doesn't really answer the question I have described here.

Comment: I realise that you probably want to apply this to more than just `uppercase`, however, for this example I would suggest just using `css` to make the text uppercase i.e. `text-transform: uppercase;`.

Comment: @RossWilson It's only an example to demonstrate the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer shortly after posting this question.

Add the following to your `AppServiceProvider::boot()` method:

```
\Blade::directive('uppercase', function () {
    return '<?php ob_start(); ?>';
});

\Blade::directive('enduppercase', function () {
    return '<?php echo strtoupper(ob_get_clean()); ?>';
});
```

I referred to this code for the idea: https://github.com/RobinRadic/blade-extensions/blob/master/src/Directives/EndspacelessDirective.php

Comment: Confirmed working in Laravel 10. Would add that running `php artisan view:clear` is important after each change for debugging purposes.